# What name can be given to the network log catcher?

Tags: naming-conventions, rename, filenames, business-rules

I have a task in which i need to name a tool that is displaying some logs of network. I want to give it a better name. Please help me to provide a better name to the tool.

Thanks

Comment: I think, Moses is a nice name. Or maybe Berta?

Comment: Hi, Moses and berta... what they are conveying ?

Comment: I think they are just nice names. IOW I want to send a ping that your question is primarily opinion based.

Comment: Ok...Thankyou so much for your great suggession :)